# Server app on Xeon E5 has 2x worse performance than on Xeon E3

Tags: c#, performance, postgresql, nhibernate, npgsql

The server app uses postgres on localhost. It works good on Xeon E3-1270 V2 @ 3.50Ghz with 16 GB RAM and handles more than 1k db requests/second. The app creates ~100 ThreadPool threads.

The same app when launched on E5 (the same configuration) uses 500 and more threads until it reaches max_connections. Sometimes transactions are executing very slow (begin takes 0.18s in avg and 15.94s max; commit takes 0.47s in avg and 15.93s max). The slow queries can be very simple like updating two integer columns in a one row. There are no problematic queries in the pg_stat_statements. I had to limit ThreadPool min/max threads to 100 otherwise postgres goes out of ram with 600+ connections.

Typical code that in some cases executes ~12sec:

```
        using (var s = HibernateSessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var tr = s.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    s.Lock(User, LockMode.None);
                }
                catch
                {
                    s.Lock(User, LockMode.None);
                }

                User.Guild = null;
                tr.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

When the app stops responding to client requests pgAdmin "Server Status" shows these queries:

```
 set extra_float_digits=3; set ssl_recognitation_limit=0; select 'npgsql12345';
 DISCARD ALL
 COMMIT
 BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITED;
```

and ~2000 granted locks
[image]
What can cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used pgbench to check the servers performance. It was either postgresql server problem or machine problems (HDD or something). In both cases this is not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data you've provided, it seems the crux of the issue is the 5x increase in threadcount -- 100 on the E3 vs. 500 on the E5. You've said they are the same configuration hardware-wise, which I assume means that each has 4 hyperthreaded cores, since that's what the E3 model you listed has according to the *Intel* spec sheet.

That means with the same number of CPU threads available, you're trying to process 5x as many threads. This also will hugely up the memory requirements, and will also up the CPU overhead, as it'll likely be thrashing around trying to context-switch between all the threads. Given that the E5 also has 16 GB of RAM (based on your same-config comment), it likely cannot cope with that added overhead.

I would look to see if you're swapping a ton to disk, which would cause terrible I/O performance, and whether things are CPU or I/O bound. I'm guessing you're running *Windows* based on the use of *C#*, so I'd recommend using something like *Resource Monitor* to look deeper into that. That is, use it to monitor the *Postgres* processes and look at their disk usage, CPU usage, etc. There are a wide variety of monitoring options available in that tool.

However, that aside, why not just run with the same workload -- 100 threads -- on the E5 that's working fine with the E3? If otherwise identically configured, the main difference (depending on exact E5 model) would be CPU frequency, which, while providing some marginal edge on a per-CPU-thread basis over the slower clock speed of the E3, would be unlikely to allow for a vast performance edge over the E3 (as opposed to, say, if your E5 had 24 cores, or 48 threads). Obviously, there would need to be some performance testing and tuning to determine the true redline, but I suspect it's a lot closer to 100 threads than 500.

If you run with 100 threads max on the E5 just as you are on the E3, is the performance fine (essentially the same)? You said it "helped", but unclear from that if it was still worse.

Comment: I don't create 500 threads but ThreadPool does because db requests going slow. The stats for E5 are taken when ThreadPool is already limited to 100 threads otherwise postgres goes out of ram with 600+ connections. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you need many connections or high performance, use a connection pool like pgBouncer or pgPool. Your application should connect to the available connections on the connection pool. With hardware like this, you should use some 20 to 50 connections between the pool and the database, and that's it. Additional connections will slow down the database. The exact number of connections depends on the usage pattern, but hundreds of connections is never a good idea, it doesn't perform well.

I have a 2 processor 12 core machine (E5, 24 hyper threads in total) that gives me max performance with just 20 connections: 2500 tps. And it's using a FusionIO-card, IO isn't a real problem. The application is written in pl/pgsql and is doing pretty complex calculations with 200GB of data.

Comment: When I don't specify a big value for max pool size for npgsql I have `Timout while getting connection from pool` exceptions.

Comment: How many connections do you have with your connection pool and how many connections does your connection pool have with the database?

Comment: Npgsql uses its own connection pool which is run inside the server app context. I specified max pool size = 1000 (to avoid timeouts) but now I think the connection pool size is tied to the max allowed threads count (as the app can't do more queries simultanously). The current num_backends value on postgres = 120 which is nearly equals to the current server app threads count.

Comment: I'll try to reduce the max pool size to 50.